# JavaFX Duplicate Series Added

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am currently learning JavaFX and am trying to create an app that shows a line chart and allows the user to change certain variables which then changes the plotted line.  The way I do this is by removing the series (and the data points within the series) and then refilling the series and adding them again as shown below.

```
    public void plot(double[] xArr, double[] yExactArr, double[] yApproxArr) {
        linePlot.getData().clear();

        if (!exactValues.getData().isEmpty()) {
            exactValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
            approxValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
            exactValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yExactArr[i]));
            approxValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yApproxArr[i]));
        }


        linePlot.getData().addAll(exactValues, approxValues);
        mainStage.show();
    }
```

However, when I do this I am getting the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added
```

This occurs as soon as `addAll()` is called the second time around.  When I print the `toString()` function of `linePlot.getData()` after calling `clear()`, it prints an empty array, so it seems like there shouldn't be a problem.  My guess is this isn't the proper way of going about changing the line but this is my newbie attempt.  It seems like I should be able to just change the data within the series (without removing and readding them) but then my plot doesn't update.

Any ideas/recommendations?

Comment: Looks like it should work (assuming you don't inadvertently have `exactValues` and `approxValues` pointing to the same list). Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 12):

This issue could also happen if you have :

```
animated="true"
```

set for your line chart. 

When the class **XYChart** checks for duplicates, it takes all the series from **displayedSeries** and compares them with your existing data series. During this time, if you have cleared the data, the series will still be in the **displayedSeries** due to the prolonged **fading effect** and result in the "duplicate series added" error.


If that is the case, simply set :

```
animated="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a JavaFX bug. I had the same problem. I "solved" it removing the chart (linePlot in your case) and creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug when changing the chart data with animation. As mentioned by @Anurag if you turn off the animation you will not face the issue.

e.g.

```
linePlot.setAnimated(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add your series once to the chart initially when creating your chart.

Update the data without adding the series again:

```
   public void plot(double[] xArr, double[] yExactArr, double[] yApproxArr) {
    linePlot.getData().clear();

    if (!exactValues.getData().isEmpty()) {
        exactValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
        approxValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
        exactValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yExactArr[i]));
        approxValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yApproxArr[i]));
    }


    //linePlot.getData().addAll(exactValues, approxValues);
    mainStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with FXML and controller I guess the best solution is to use Initilizable interface in controller, and initialize function from it. In initialize you define

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {   
      linePlot.getData().addAll(exactValues, approxValues);
}
```

Also you have to add your function to Controller In this way you add series just once, but you can edit data from them by using your function.

```
public void plot(double[] xArr, double[] yExactArr, double[] yApproxArr) {
    linePlot.getData().clear();

    if (!exactValues.getData().isEmpty()) {
        exactValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
        approxValues.getData().remove(0, xArr.length - 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
        exactValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yExactArr[i]));
        approxValues.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArr[i], yApproxArr[i]));
    }

}
```

In main you will have

```
@Override
public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("your FXML file"));
    mainStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 989, 583));
    mainStage.show();

}
```